# Add MySQL geospatial Point column in Laravel 4 migration

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, geospatial

1. How do I add a Point column in my Laravel 4 migration for a MySQL database?
2. Is it possible to setup database independent migrations using a check if mysql and check if postgres statement? And if so how could I go about doing that?

I've tried:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('meetings', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->enum('category',[0,1,2,3,4])->index();

        $table->unsignedInteger('owner_id');
        $table->foreign('owner_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->dateTime('start_date');
        $table->dateTime('end_date');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
    DB::raw("ALTER TABLE meetings ADD COLUMN geolocation POINT"); 
}
```

But this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `statement` method:

```
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE meetings ADD COLUMN geolocation POINT");
```

**Update**

About the second question, you can access to `database.php` file like this:

```php
if (Config::get('database')['default'] === 'mysql'){
    // mysql 
}else if (Config::get('database')['default'] === 'pgsql'){
    // PostgreSQL
}
```